# How to set up a linear mixed effect model with stratified intercept in R

Tags: r, mixed-model

I want to fit a mixed effect model, where I estimate a stratified intercept for each group included. I also want the effect from x to vary by group.

My first attempt was to set the intercept to 0 like this:

```
lmer(outcome ~ 0 + group + x + y + (0 + x|group), data)
```

Is this the right way to do it? Or are there other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proposed model:

```
lmer(outcome ~ 0 + group + x + y + (0 + x|group), data)
```

has the following features:

1. No overall intercept
2. No random intercepts
3. Fixed effects for the grouping variable `group`
4. Random slopes for the variable `x` for each `group`

So what this is saying is that, overall there is no intercept but every group has a diferent intercept due to the fixed effect of `group`, and it's own slope for `x` which will be an offset from the overall (fixed) "effect" of `x`. That means your data should all have approximately the same value when `x` is 0, and should then diverge. That means it should look something like this (where I am ignoring the variable `y`)

[image]

So, if it does, then the proposed model should fit the bill.

Of course there are other patterns that are compatible with this model, such as:

[image]

the main point here is that, when `x` is zero, all the groups have approximatetely the same value (since the global intercept is zero and there are no random intercepts)

Comment: Isn't including a fixed effect for group equivalent to a separate intercept for each group?

Comment: @DavidLukeThiessen Sure ! There's a lot of interesting things going on in this model :)

Comment: So "every group has an intercept of zero" isn't correct then?

Comment: @RobertLong thank you for this comprehensive and visually illustrated response! I do wonder though about what David Luke Thiessen said. When I fit the model R gives me an intercept for every group, like it was intended.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, the lines don't all cross he intercept at exactly the same place, because of different estimates for each group, so each group has it's own intercept - but not random intercepts

Comment: @RobertLong oh I see, thank you really much!